# Directing 2 actions to the same view, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two actions set up to get specific items from database as follows:

routes.rb

```
match 'bibles' => 'documents#bibles'
match 'postcards' => 'documents#postcards'
```

documents_controller.rb

```
 def bibles
   @pagetitle = "Browse all Bibles"
   @documents = Document.where(:document_type_id => 1).paginate(:page =>params[:page], :order =>'id desc', :per_page =>50)
 end

def postcards
  @pagetitle = "Browse all Postcards"
  @documents = Document.where(:document_type_id => 3).paginate(:page =>params[:page], :order =>'id desc', :per_page =>50)
end
```

These render a specific view, both of which consist of the same code, `bibles.html.erb` and `postcards.html.erb`.  I need this to point to the same view.  Is there a parameter to add to the route that will do this, or is my routing incorrect for this purpose?

Comment: Edited to replace `controllers` by `actions` .... you have two actions in the same controller here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add  `render "documents"` to your actions, and name your view `documents.html.erb`.

Comment: Also keep in mind @simonmorley's answer and my comment to him.   Wrapping the respond with `respond_to` or `respond_with` is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of each method add:

```
render "documents/index"
```

Then create the view `app/views/documents/index.html.erb` and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using `render` you can specify what partial you want to render. Read more at [api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

Answer (score 0):

For my own reference - another way:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.text {render :template=>"app/views/documents/index.html.erb" }
end
```

Comment: respond_with is the "rails 3 version" of respond_to:  http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3

Comment: Funny timing, I just got a depreciation waring about the same in my tests. Was just about to remove!